# Two browser windows hitting same MySQL app, both can't run at the same time

Tags: mysql, php, apache-2.4

I have a LAMP web application that has some pages that do quite a bit of processing and take a while to complete. Sometimes as the developer I like to do two things at once as I'm working on a feature. So I may have more than one browser window open at a time. One of them may be PhpMyAdmin, or I might be evaluating two pages that use the same feature to make sure things match, or whatever.

What I'm noticing is that if I have one browser window open on a page that is processing and loading, I can't do anything else in another browser window on the same PC until the first one completes. So in Window 1, processing may take 30 seconds. Window 2 may be a simple click on a table in PhpMyAdmin, or I may be trying to browse back to the main page which usually loads quickly. But both of those things just sit and spin until Window 1 completes what ever it's doing, then bam - Window 2 is loaded. This is not true if Window 2 is on another PC. But that second PC also has the same limitation of only on Window working at a time.

This clearly seems like there's a setting somewhere where either Apache or MySQL or PHP or something can only handle one thread per connection at a time. But I'm not sure where to look as I'm not all that familiar with configuration settings on either of them. Can anyone tell me where I should be looking?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your mysql seem to hit 100% cpu or hit too much your IO. Can you validate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with PHP and it can't handle more than one process simultaneously due to a bad configuration.

Comment: yagmoth555 - I can run things on another PC at the same time with no loss in performance noticed. All other users continue to function fine, so I don't think MySQL is at 100%.

André - Yes that is entirely possible, but I'm not sure what setting(s) I should look at. Can you suggest? 

Thank you both

Answer (score 0):

If Window 1 is performing an operation that locks a table or row that Window 2 needs, then Window 2 will just have to wait until Window 1 releases the lock. The fix is to choose the correct table and transaction type, and design your application to release locks quickly.

Comment: No locks in place. I can run the same process on another PC at the same time - or another process accessing the same tables - with no problem. But that PC also can only do one thing at a time.